# Does mass of orbiting body affect the orbital speed?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon

Does mass of orbiting body affect the orbital speed? Suppose if Moon is at same distance from Earth as International Space Station. Would Moon's orbital velocity change? Also secondary question, Theoretically and practically is possible that Moon can orbit in low earth orbit (same as ISS), meaning will Moon disintegrate or it will stay intact?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've added an answer that might be more helpful and complete to this particular user and question.

Comment: This question is closed, so I have added a late answer to the duplicate. The answer to the question is yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does mass of orbiting body affect the orbital speed?

**tl;dr:** Yes it always does, about half as much. If it's small, like one millionth the mass of the primary, the change in speed is one half of one millionth for example. In the extreme case when the two masses are equal though the trend breaks down and the speed is now 70.7% ($\sqrt{1/2}$ ) rather than half.

If you removed the Moon and put a small rock there, it would orbit 0.6% faster than the Moon. Jupiter is about 1/1000 of the Sun or 0.1% the mass. **If you removed Jupiter and put a small planet there, it would orbit 0.05% faster than Jupiter does!**

---

Wikipedia's [Two body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem) and [Circular orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_orbit) are helpful but I found that the [cnx.org](https://cnx.org/) page [15. Two body system - circular motion](https://cnx.org/contents/1AJmkLE0@2.9:HvIAxsFc@4/Two-body-system-circular-motion) has a particularly straightforward treatment of the circular two body problem.

[image: two body circular orbits] Commons Attribution 4.0 License.

Use

$$r = r_1 + r_2$$

$$m_1 r_1 = m_2 r_2$$

$$\frac{v_1}{r_1} = \frac{v_2}{r_2}$$

$$\omega_1 = \omega_2 = \omega \ \ \text{ orbital angular speed}$$

$$M = m_1 + m_2$$

$$m_2 = M\frac{r_1}{r_1 + r_2}$$

...then some math and physics happens...

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r^3}} = sqrt{\frac{G(m_1+m_2)}{r^3}}$$

Orbital speed of each body would just be the angular speed $omega$ times each body's radius:

$$v_1 = \omega r_1$$

$$v_2 = \omega r_2$$

$$r2  = r \frac{m_1}{M}$$

$$v_2 = \omega r_2 = \omega r \frac{m_1}{M} = \sqrt{\frac{G(m_1+m_2)}{r^3}}  r \frac{m_1}{M}$$

It can be shown that if $m_1$ (i.e. mass of Earth) is constant and the separation between the two $r$ is constant then the *change in speed* is half as fast as the ratio of masses as long as it's still fairly small.

For example if the mass of the small object is one millionth of the mass of the large object, then the change in speed (compared to massless small object) *is one half of one millionth*.

For the Moon we have say $m_2 = m_1 / 81$, then

$v_2$ = 0.9939
$r_2$ = 0.9878
$\omega$ = 1.0062
and
$\omega r_2$ = 0.9939

The moon having 1.23% of Earth's mass would move 0.61% slower than a tiny satellite.

This "half the difference" trend breaks down when the two masses become closer to equal.

If the second object were the same mass as the Earth, this trend says the speed would be half of the tiny satellite, but it turns out the speed is $\sqrt{1/2}$ or 70.7% rather than 50%.

[image: two body speed]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m1 = 1.0

m2 = np.logspace(-10, 0, 101)

M = m1 + m2

r = 1.0
G = 1

omega = np.sqrt(G * M / r**3)
r2  = r * m1 / M
v2 = omega * r2

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(m2, v2)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylim(None, 1.02)
plt.ylabel('v(m2=0) - v "how much slower"')
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(m2, 1 - v2)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('m2 with m1 = 1')
plt.ylabel('v(m2=0) - v "how much slower"')
plt.suptitle('G = r = m1 = 1')
plt.show()
```

Comment: @CarlWitthoft **There are no failing formulae here** at least to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft only the linear *trend* breaks down and that's exactly what the equations show. I'm just describing what happens. The curves in the plots start bending over.

Comment: Look, I was just trying to suggest, possibly confusingly, that the concept of "orbit" itself doesn't mean a whole lot when the barycenter starts moving drastically.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There are no "moving orbits" or moving barycenter here. I've just discussed how one parameter changes in relation to another. I can plot the volume of a soup can as a function of aspect ratio for a given area, it doesn't mean there is *an actual metal soup can* changing shape in real time. *It's a function.*

Comment: @uhoh My understanding is that object in orbit is equivalent to falling forever and also that if there is no air resistance then object falls at the same speed regardless of mass. Can you please explain how it differs from your explanation?

Comment: @jrp For a given distance two bodies can only have one orbital speed (for circular orbits). So a 10,000 kg satellite and a 10 kg satellite will orbit at *almost exactly* the same speed. But not exactly, because the two bodies orbit around their center of mass, so if you keep the Earth the same mass and the size of the orbit the same, a very heavy satellite will orbit very slightly slower because it has to move the Earth around too! So If you removed our Moon and put a small rock there, it would orbit 0.61% faster than the Moon does, because it has much less effect on the Earth.

Comment: @jrp I haven't talked at all about air or drag or decay. I just talked about how the orbital speed depends on the mass of the smaller object as well as the larger one.

Comment: @jrp the mass of Jupiter is about 1/1000 of the Sun or 0.1% lighter. If you removed Jupiter and put a small planet there, it would orbit 0.05% faster than Jupiter does! I like that so much I'm going to add it to the answer!

Comment: @uhoh Thank for explanation!. If possible, can you please explain second question - if we put Moon in the orbit same as ISS, will earth-moon system be stable or Moon will disintegrate?

Comment: @jrp I ignored that because the ISS is only 400 km above the surface of the Earth, and the [Moon's radius 1737 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon)! So about 40% of the Moon would be inside the Earth. That's why I left the Moon where it is in the answer. :-)  If you moved the Moon close but not touching, it could cause all kinds of problems, but that should be a new question since it has to do with the [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit) and there are plenty of other Q&A here about that you can check first.

Comment: @jrp it's always better to ask more questions than to put multiple questions into one question post, because different people will have good/different answers to the different questions. There's no limit to how many (good) questions you can ask in Stack Exchange!

Comment: @uhoh ahh, I didn't think through Moon radius :facepalm:, I am just getting started to be active on stack exchange, thanks for suggestion on asking questions. I appreciate that you took time to clarifying my questions. Thank you.

Comment: @jrp no problem. SE is fun, enjoy!